# Error installing Alfresco Community 4.0.b - Unterminated Uqoted String

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, alfresco

When trying to install Alfresco 4.0.b in text mode on Ubuntu 10.04, I get the error:

```
./alfresco-community-4.0.b-installer-linux-x64.bin: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Is this related to the installer or Ubuntu?  Some help to get it running?

Comment: My hunch is that you have a corrupt download - can you check the MD5 hash of your file and verify it's correct?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark an answer or add your own answer if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue but resolved it by making sure the .bin was executable by:

```
chmod 777 <filename>
```

You also need to run it as root and have './' before the filename:

```
$ ./alfresco-community-4.0.b-installer-linux-x64.bin
```

I used `sh` as I'm used to running shell/bash scripts. I think that's why it came up with the "unquoted string' error.

Could also have been that I used `chmod +a` instead of `chmod 777`.

Answer (score 1):

Either corruption, or you are working on 32bit Operating System, use the command : uname -m to know this, if it gives something other than :   x86_64 then you are not using a compatible version of UBUNTU, you have either to install a 64bit release of UBUNTU or choose the hard coded installation of Alfresco since the 4th version doesn't have a 32bit Alfresco installer.